# Как в XML достать значение атрибута у элемента?

Tags: c#, linq2xml

Есть простейший xml-документ:

```
<Шапка>
  <error code="40" message="Can not login." /> 
</Шапка>
```

Требуется оттуда достать "40".

С моей точки зрения, надо достать значение атрибута code у элемента error.

Типа такого:

```
 return (from node in xdoc.Descendants() select node.Element("error").Attribute("code").Value).First();
```

Не срабатывает. Почему? Как правильно написать?

И вдогонку, это ведь то же самое, что:

```
<Шапка>
 <error>
  <code>40</code>
  <message>Can not login</message>
 </error> 
</Шапка>
```

Верно?

Comment: Нет, не одно и тоже, т.к. в первом примере xml code - аттрибут, а во втором примере code уже тег. Следовательно код который вы привели для второго варианта не годится.

Comment: по логической структуре - тоже самое, но в остальном они довольно сильно различаются. Второй вариант более предпочтителен, как более гибкий.

Comment: Народ, я рад, что вы считаете второй вариант (который придумал я) лучше чем первый (который мне шлет сервер), но я не могу взять и изменить структуру ответа с сервера. Жду ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Ваш код рабочий. Приведите исходный XML. Вполне вероятно, что там объявляются пространства имён, которые вы не учитываете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Был пропущен XNamespace(!)

*facepalm*

Решение и обсуждение было [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811639/receiving-error-code-value-from-xml-file)

Comment: Это разве не ваш вопрос? http://hashcode.ru/questions/112356/

Comment: @mantigatos, у меня возникают периодические провалы в памяти. :) А если серьезно, то реально какое-то затмение нашло... Рядом в этом же классе было написано два десятка методов с этим же неймспейсом, но я все равно сидел и тупил. Ничем такое объяснить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает:

```
xdoc.Descendants("error").First().Attribute("code").Value;
```

Comment: Ага. А вот у меня - нет. И на SO мне тоже пишут, что работает. Так что ошибка где-то в другом месте... Черт его знает, буду разбираться.

Comment: @Olter: посмотрите, что выдают:

* `xdoc.Descendants("error").ToList()`?
* `xdoc.Descendants("error").First()`?
* `xdoc.Descendants("error").First().Attribute("code")`?

---
Отменяется, проблема, как вы пишете, не в этом.

Answer (score -1):

посмотрите в сторону XMLTextReader из пространства System.Xml

[Ссылка на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Ссылка на сторонний блог](http://dblog.ucoz.ru/blog/2009-03-20-10)

P.S. Попробуйте вытягивать значения не LINQ, а традиционным способом.

Comment: Извините, но это не ответ.